# Is there a palette app with a movable glass to convert text color code into a color?

Tags: colors

I have a text with `#000000` colors, and I'd like to move a rectangular glass over it and see the color.

It'd be helpful if I could rest the glass, choose another color in the app and have the text be modified accordingly.

Comment: Knowing your operating system would help!

Comment: gnulix or windo.

Comment: I'm not sure we have the same problem - but if so, [the Color Picker from Microsoft PowerToys](https://superuser.com/a/1809105/76395) might be a good answer here.

Answer (score 1):

[Colorbox](http://pourpre.com/colorbox/indexen.php) is a simple and powerfull software which make you able to do exactly what you want with colors

Comment: +1 for apparently understanding exactly what was wanted from that explaination.